# Install Laravel on GIT as well as LOCALHOST also on my PC

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-4

Hii i need to **install laravel on my localhost as well as on git repository**.

As i am new to laravel and git both, i am unable to start.

I am working on LINUX and intsalled the GIT through terminal.

Now what to do next,i am unable to proceed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should first install laravel. You can just follow [these steps](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation), but the easiest way IMO is to install [Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead). The two methods are easy enough, you should try it.

Then you could read some documentation [about git](https://git-scm.com/doc), how to init or clone a repository and update your question if it is unclear. Hope it will help!